# How to run several cucumber scenarios with the same first four steps but with different succeeding steps and avoid duplicate

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have several scenarios in my feature file that have duplicate steps in the first four lines and has different steps in the succeeding lines, initially I wrote it with all the steps per scenario but I get the duplicate error. Please see scenario below:

```
    Background: Login to ODB Portal
      Given that the user wanted to login at the <site>
      And user is on the <site> Page
      When user enters Email as <email> and Password as <password>
      And user click on login button
      Then the <site> Dashboard is displayed
      When the user click on Users Menu Item

    @AddNewUser
    Scenario: Add New User
      When the user click on +Add New User button
      Then user can view Add New User window
      When the user enters Account Details
      And the user enters Profile Details
      And the user enters Payment Method
      And click on Add New User button
      Then the user is created
      And has the status of "Pending"
      When user click on logout button
      Then login page is displayed
      And close the browser

    @EditUser
    Scenario: Edit Existing User
      When user click on the email link from the list of users
      Then user can view User window
      When user click on View User Information button
      Then user can view Passenger Profile
      When user click on Update User Information button
      And the user updates Profile Details
      And click on Update User button
      Then Passenger Profile is updated
      And close the browser

    @RemoveUser
    Scenario: Remove User
      When user click on the email link from the list of users
      Then user can view User window
      When user click on View User Information button
      Then user can view Passenger Profile
      When user click on Remove User or Ban User button
      Then the window Are you Sure? is displayed
      And click on Remove User button
      And click anywhere on the page
      Then the user is removed and is not displayed on the list
      And close the browser

    @BanUser
    Scenario: Remove User
      When user click on the email link from the list of users
      Then user can view User window
      When user click on View User Information button
      Then user can view Passenger Profile
      When user click on Remove User or Ban User button
      Then the window Are you Sure? is displayed
      And click on Ban User button
      And click anywhere on the page
      Then the user is removed and is not displayed on the list
      And close the browser
```

Now I thought of creating a new scenario that comprises of the first four lines to separate them and thought of running them both, so in test runner I wrote in the tags= "ViewUserInformation or @EditUser", my problem is it wont work if I use **AND** and only works on **OR**, but although it works I got an error when it is running @EditUser tag since the browser logout and closed in @ViewUserInformation, so when running @EditUser after clicking the User Menu Item it fails because it still needs the steps from @ViewUserInformation. Do you have any advice on how to make this works without the duplicate scenario errors?.

Below is the updated scenario:

```
    Background: Login to ODB Portal
      Given that the user wanted to login at the <site>
      And user is on the <site> Page
      When user enters Email as <email> and Password as <password>
      And user click on login button
      Then the <site> Dashboard is displayed
      When the user click on Users Menu Item

    @AddNewUser
    Scenario: Add New User
      When the user click on +Add New User button
      Then user can view Add New User window
      When the user enters Account Details
      And the user enters Profile Details
      And the user enters Payment Method
      And click on Add New User button
      Then the user is created
      And has the status of "Pending"
      When user click on logout button
      Then login page is displayed
      And close the browser

    @ViewUserInformation
    Scenario: View User Information
      When user click on the email link from the list of users
      Then user can view User window
      When user click on View User Information button
      Then user can view Passenger Profile
      And close the browser

    @EditUser
    Scenario: Edit Existing User
      When user click on Update User Information button
      And the user updates Profile Details
      And click on Update User button
      Then Passenger Profile is updated
      And close the browser

    @RemoveUser
    Scenario: Remove User
      When user click on Remove User or Ban User button
      Then the window Are you Sure? is displayed
      And click on Remove User button
      And click anywhere on the page
      Then the user is removed and is not displayed on the list
      And close the browser

    @BanUser
    Scenario: Remove User
      When user click on Remove User or Ban User button
      Then the window Are you Sure? is displayed
      And click on Ban User button
      And click anywhere on the page
      Then the user is removed and is not displayed on the list
      And close the browser
```

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting. Also, if you want to run steps that are common for all tests and you do not want to duplicate the steps in each scenario, what's wrong with using `Background`? 1) You are already using it, and 2) That is precisely what `Background` is for. The steps in the background run before each scenario in a feature.

Comment: Background cannot contain variables, so you'll have to specify those

Comment: I wanted to make the @ViewUserInformation steps be run by all scenario without putting them in the background, because not all scenario covers those steps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to do the login part but possibly use different credentials correct? If this is the case, you can create one Step_Definition step in any of the classes (doesn't have to be related to the scenario) and use data table to get your variables, ie:

```
Given user is logged in with <Email> and <Password>
| Email   | Password  |
  abc@d.f   123456
```

Comment: Your answer should not contain a question. If the version is important, state "The latest Version" or 'Version XXX" applies to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have figured it out, the steps in @ViewUserInformation will be included in the feature file but will not be included in the step definitions, that way these steps will still be called in other scenarios without having a duplicate.